# Tying two Tzitziot together

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, tying-knots-kosheir

I think I read somewhere that the Mishna Berura permits this following idea. Taking two different strings (e.g. extra short ones) and tying them together to make one big string to be used for making Tzitzit? Would this be Mutar? Sources appreciated more than logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

משנה ברורה סימן יב:ז

שאלה חוטי הציצית שנפסקו וחזר וקשרן אם מועיל מה שנעשו שלמים ע"י קשירה ומסקי האחרונים דדינא הכי אם מתחלה קודם שעשה הציצית מהחוטין נפסקו החוטין וקשרן בקשר קיימא ואח"כ עשה מהן ציצית כשר דקשירה הוי חיבור גמור וכן לאחר שנעשה בהכשר דהיינו אם נפסק ראש אחד לאחר הטלת הציצית בהבגד אף אם לא נשתייר בו כדי עניבה מהני לקשרו עתה ואף אם יפסק אח"כ ראש השני מאותו החוט יהיה כשר כיון שבעת הקשירה היה הציצית כשר אבל אם נתקצרו החוטין באופן שנפסלו הציצית עי"ז כגון שנפסקו שני ראשין ולא נשתיירו כדי עניבה או שנפסק החוט במקום הנקב לא מהני מה שחזר אח"כ וקשר דזהו בכלל תעשה ולא מן העשוי בפסול וכ"ש אם היה החוט קצר משיעורו בתחלתו בשעת עשייה בודאי לא מהני מה שחזר אח"כ וקשרו לאחר הכריכה והקשירה של חוליא ראשונה דזהו ממש תעשה ולא מן העשוי וכדלעיל בסימן י"א סעיף י"ג לענין חתך ראשי החוטין:

In short, The Mishna Berura does indeed say this is acceptable. However, you need to tie the pieces together *before* tying the strings on to the clothing.

I have seen this done by someone who bought one Raavad set of techelet (one blue string), cut it in half and tied each half to some white to make two sets of Rambam techelet (one half-blue half-white string).

I caution you against doing this because if the knot holding the two parts ever does come undone, you have to untie and retie the *entire corner* for it to be kosher again. It is simply not worth the effort.

Comment: The Talmud and meschet Tzizit itself allow this to be done if the strings break.

Comment: @avi I can't confirm or deny. The question asked about the Mishna Brurah's psak. If you can provide early sources that would be wonderful.

Comment: sorry that was meant to be a comment on the question not the answer

Comment: Thank you. The last point is also something to take into consideration. The thing is I can make two Begadim with one Raavad.